# Argparse won't parse any arguments I pass in the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm trying to run my program in Terminal:

```
py program.py -t
```

and it's not setting the boolean to False. From what I can see, all of my code looks correct.

```
isTitle = True

a = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='program.py', usage='%(prog) [options]', description='The fooiest of bar')
a.add_argument('-t', '--title', action='store_const', const=False, dest='isTitle', help='show title')
r = a.parse_args()
```

I have a statement after the parse_args that prints the isTitle boolean to verify it's been set, and it always returns True. Do you guys have any recommendations? I can add more code/diagnostic statements if need be. Thank you!

Comment: I encourage posters to print the `Namespace` returned by `parse_args`.  `print(r)`.  That gives the clearest idea of what the parser is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dest='isTitle'` doesn't mean that a *variable* named `isTitle` will be changed, it means the value will be stored in `r.isTitle`, i.e. in the object the `parse_args` call returns. It would be madness for argparse to modify any variables in the global scope.

What you want is simply:

```
a.add_argument('-t', '--title', action='store_true', dest='isTitle', help='show title')
r = a.parse_args()
print(r.isTitle)
```